# How can I get the date in 24 hours format

Tags: ios, formatting, nsdate, nstimeinterval

```
NSDate *localDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval timeZoneOffset = [[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMTForDate:localDate];
NSDate *gmtDate = [localDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-timeZoneOffset];
```

This gives me time in 12 hours format. So, for example it is is 2.15 pm. It gives me 2016-01-16 02:15:00 +0000.

However, I want in 24 hours format like 14:15:00. Also I want just the time. How can I get that.

Comment: Please have a look at the code. I find no way to convert a date from 12 hours to 24 hours using date formatter. I needed my time to be in GMT. It's is not that i didn't do research. I just didn't find the right direction. If I am doing anything wrong then at least point me to the right direction. Right now, doing NSDate *now =[NSDate date]; is giving me 2016-01-16 08:46:33 +0000 which is nothing near 2:50 pm. So, if there is another way then please suggest that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a string that represents time in the format you need, try use NSDateFormatter with setting it GMT `timeZone` and desired `dateFormat` (`HH:mm:ss` in your case)

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    NSLog(@"Current time in GMT = %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

This would print time in format like `12:34:56` in GMT timezone

For more info on about date formats see [this fine article](http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/)